# Is there a way to focus on a text element (div,h tags, span) for screen readers

Tags: javascript, html, screen-readers

I have a popup on my page and it opens on certain condition, like adding more than n number of items in the basket.
When the popup opens, the close button of the popup is 'focused'. 
So a user using a screenreader would have no idea which close button they are hearing about.

Is there a way to focus on the text first so that the user is aware of the popup and what it says, allowing them to have the same experience as a normal user?

I tried changing the order of the HTML elements(ex: text element first and button after) but that didn't work.

```
<div class="popup__container" style="opacity: 1; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
  <a href="#" class="popup__logo">
    <svg class="icon">
      <use xlink:href="#icon-logo"></use>
    </svg>
  </a>
  <button class="popup__close">
    <span>Close</span>
    <svg class="icon">
      <use xlink:href="#icon-close"></use>
    </svg>
  </button>
  <div class="popup__content">
    <div id="{9B6A4-272-46F7-9E21-4CE80C73A}" class="no-startendmargin theme-white" data-label-close="Close">
      <p>Starting from 15 products, you get a exclusive discount, find out more <a href="#groupProduct">Group product</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [`tab-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Comment: As per my understanding and trials, tab-index doesn't makes the element get focused by default or through JS, it is just to allows the element to be selected by pressing tab(indexes the element for tabbing). - @zer00ne

Comment: Then your understanding is partial, please read [tab-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Comment: I spent a good amount of time reading that again, so what it says is, tabindex makes the element focusable from keyboard and not from javascript, which means, if you press tab, focus will jump to that element if that is the next in the list, i tried focusing through js and jquery by triggering focus or even a tabkey press(key 9), after adding the the tabindex. didn't work. @zer00ne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what you should do is implement a modal dialog.

If you want a simpler solution for modern browsers, consider using the HTML5 native `<dialog>` element, [MDN link is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog). Thus you'll get the Close button, focusability and even Windows-like experience and cursor restriction (seems to be a JAWS-specific feature), all of that free of charge.

If for some reason the native solution is not suitable for you, consider using plugins like [Modaal](https://github.com/humaan/modaal) or manually adding corresponding ARIA roles like `dialog`, for instance.

Comment: This helps, 
adding the role dialog makes the screen-reader read the content of the popup without event focusing on the text, Thanks a lot for this input.
I will have more questions coming for you :)

Comment: Please feel free to ask :).

Comment: I have a question regarding accessibility, can you please check.

Comment: Yes, what do you want me to check? :)